# Sybase SQL join RESULT SET

Tags: sql, sybase

I have a problem with a result set of two tables.

I create  two tables.

```
 create table person
    (ID int not null  PRIMARY KEY,
     NAME varchar (50) 
    )

create table address
       ( ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
         PERSON_ID int not null,
         ADDRESS VARCHAR (20) null, 
         ZIP int)
insert into person (ID, NAME) values ( 1,'Hans') 
insert into person values (2,'Peter')

insert into address values (1,1, 'Andernach',56626)   
insert into address values (2,2,'Koblenz',56000)  
insert into address values (3,3,'Neuwied',56100)
```

I would like to get a result set of these tables.

If I use this query with `p.ID = a.PERSON_ID`
I get right result.

BUT if I use query with `p.ID != a.PERSON_ID`
I get a lot of results

```
select  a.ADDRESS,
        a.ZIP,
        a.PERSON_ID,
        p.NAME
from address a,
     person p
 where a.PERSON_ID != p.ID
```

My question: Why do I get a lot of results with `!=`?

Thanks
:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because lots of rows in the first table don't match lots of rows in the second.  In fact, almost all rows in the second will match *each* in the first.  Presumably you want:

```
select  a.ADDRESS,
        a.ZIP,
        a.PERSON_ID,
        p.NAME
from person p left join
     address a
     on a.PERSON_ID = p.ID 
where p.id is null;
```

This gets rows in `person` that don't have an address.  (Putting the tables in the other order or using `right join` would get addresses with no person.)